# How do I listen for react-router location change in redux reducer?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router

I have a React Redux app, and am trying to listen for a `react-router` location change in one of my reducers.  I am using `hashHistory`, not `browserHistory`.  In my Redux devtools, I can see it is firing an action when the location changes:

[image]

However, in my reducer, when I listen for 'LOCATION_CHANGE', it doesn't catch anything.

```
import * as types from '../constants/actionTypes';
import objectAssign from 'object-assign';
import initialState from './initialState';

export default function listingsReducer(state = initialState.listings, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'LOCATION_CHANGE': {
        console.log(action); //currently doesn't get into this case block
        return state;
    }
    default:
        return state;
  }
}
```

What do I have to use in order to handle this action in my reducer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change `case 'LOCATION_CHANGE'` to `case '@@router/LOCATION_CHANGE'`.

Answer (score 9):

Even better, use the constant provided by `react-router` :

```js
import { LOCATION_CHANGE } from 'connected-react-router';

// ...

switch (action.type) {
    case LOCATION_CHANGE: {}
}
```

Comment: Question--is `LOCATION_CHANGE` a constant provided by React-Router or Connected-React-Router? Also, I've as yet been unable to find any actual documentation on this constant. Any idea why?

Comment: Definitely coming from `connected-react-router` (https://github.com/supasate/connected-react-router/blob/master/src/actions.js#L5)
And the documentation might be a bit lacking. But since it is a standard way for naming redux actions, maybe they thought it wasn't necessary.